# alias to detach screen when I exit (and kill ssh)

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I auto start gnu screen when I ssh into one on my own servers. When I am done, I have to d to detach. Then exit to quit ssh. This means that when I ssh into the server again at some point in time, I can continue where I left off.

Can I create a alias (for instance) that will (from within screen) detach and drop ssh?

Comment: How do you auto-start `screen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting `screen` when logging in on the remote host (executed on your local machine):

```
ssh -t user@host screen
```

In the screen session, on the remote host, to detach and log out (which would end the SSH session unless you are using a persistent connection using a control socket (i.e. using the `ControlMaster` setting with `ControlPersist` in `~/.ssh/config`)):

```
screen -d
```

Later, to log in and re-attach:

```
ssh -t user@host screen -r
```

Note that you have to use `-t` with `ssh`, forcing pseudo-terminal allocation, to start `screen` in this way.

The alias on the remote host would be for `screen -d`, maybe `detach='screen -d'` or something similar.

On the local host, you could have a section in your `~/.ssh/config` file saying

```
Host *-screen
    RequestTTY force
    RemoteCommand screen -d -R

Host myhost myhost-screen
    HostName myhost.somedomain.example.com
    User myname
```

Then, whenever you use

```
ssh myhost-screen
```

a `screen` session would be created (or re-attached to) on the specified host, while

```
ssh myhost
```

would not use `screen`.

Note: `RemoteCommand` was added in OpenSSH 7.6 (2017-10-03).

---

For `tmux`:

- Use `tmux new-session -A -s "%n"` in `~/.ssh/config` instead of `screen -d -R`.
- Use <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> or `tmux detach-client` or `tmux detach` to detach.

Comment: Nice, thx.  At home this will work great. I did not know about 'Force pseudo-tty allocation'. I tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute  your screen command to recall or create your screen ,
**After**  you add a a kill of you parent shell , so you will kill you ssh connection .

a example to kill my parent process if the parent is bash

```
kill $( ps -ax -o pid,ppid,args | grep "^$$ " |  grep bash | awk '{print $2} ' )
```

Comment: Thx. If I ssh in from somewhere where I can not specify a app to run (like online ssh https://app.shellngn.com/) , and I modify your line of code to look for ssh sessions, this will work.